# insertBefore next visible sibling?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a table plugin to allow me to move rows. (https://github.com/isocra/TableDnD)

This seems to work well, but I have one slight issue.   My table is a standard HTML table and I'm grouping some rows together and showing/hiding them based on an icon click.

If the hidden rows are visible when I drop a new row before them that works fine, I show the rows and they appear in the correct order.

If I drop a new row before them when they are hidden, then when shown the new row appears in the wrong order.

I want to make sure the plugin only adds the row before a visible row.

This is the code adding the row:

```js
moveVerticle: function (moving, currentRow) {
  if (
    0 != moving.vertical &&
    // If we're over a row then move the dragged row to there so that the user sees the
    // effect dynamically
    currentRow &&
    this.dragObject != currentRow &&
    this.dragObject.parentNode == currentRow.parentNode
  )
    (0 > moving.vertical &&
      this.dragObject.parentNode.insertBefore(
        this.dragObject,
        currentRow.nextSibling
      )) ||
      (0 < moving.vertical &&
        this.dragObject.parentNode.insertBefore(this.dragObject, currentRow));
},
```

How do I make `&& this.dragObject.parentNode.insertBefore(this.dragObject, currentRow.nextSibling)` add before the next visible sibling ?

Comment: Try something like `$(currentRow).nextAll(":visible").first()[0]`

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks I'll try this and see how I get on.

Comment: Thanks this seems to do what I need :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using [jquery] you can change the

```
currentRow.nextSibling
```

to get the next visibile sibling as a DOM node (not a jquery object) using:

```
$(currentRow).nextAll(":visible").first()[0]
```

Don't use `next(":visible")` as that's `.next().filter(":visible")` and the `[0]` converts the jquery object back to a DOM node.  `$(currentRow).nextAll(":visible")[0]` would probably also work.